# Django templatetag without value and object to return True or False

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to create a templatetag to check if multiple condition are true.

Here Is what I have tried:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def is_special():
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.profile.status.slug == "special" and request.path in "/about/":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But when I try to load and test "is_special" in the template. I don't get any thing.

```
{% if is_special %}
    display something
{% else %}
    display default
{% endif %}
```

Is this the right way to make a templatetag?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `{% if is_special %}`, it isn't running your template tag, it is checking to see whether the variable `is_special` is True or False.

To assign the result of a template tag to a variable, you want an [assignment tag]. You also need to pass the `request` object to your tag.

```
@register.assignment_tag
def is_special(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.profile.status.slug == "special" and request.path in "/about/":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then in your template:

```
{# run the tag #}
{% is_special request as is_special_result %}

{# use the result #}
{% if is_special_result %}
    display something
{% else %}
    display default
{% endif %}
```

Finally, you need to make sure the `request` is in your template's context. The easiest way to do this is to make sure you have enabled the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request). Then, the `request` will be available if you use generic class based views or the `render` shortcut.

Comment: `'is_spcial' received too many positional arguments` is the error I get. I have added request to the templatetag, and turned on request template context processor.

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot what the problem is from that error message.